# Oozie - jar file truncated when copied to lib folder on Cloudera

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, oozie

I have created a Java action and deployed it using Hue of Cloudera. I have noticed that the jar file has been copied to the /lib folder of the workspace but truncated to exact 64MB (happened on both case of jar file from some other hdfs folder, and using sharelib).

I followed the link of https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Oozie-Java-Action-ClassNotFoundException/td-p/4761 but after copying the jar to workspace /lib folder the workflow failed with server error (500).

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py  111     get_response
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/hue/apps/oozie/src/oozie/decorators.py     52  decorate
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/hue/apps/oozie/src/oozie/views/editor.py   335     submit_workflow
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/hue/apps/oozie/src/oozie/views/editor.py   356     _submit_workflow
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/hue/desktop/libs/liboozie/src/liboozie/submittion.py   79  run
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/hue/desktop/libs/liboozie/src/liboozie/submittion.py   144     deploy
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/hue/desktop/libs/liboozie/src/liboozie/submittion.py   281     _do_as
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/hue/desktop/libs/liboozie/src/liboozie/submittion.py   275     _copy_files
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-1.cdh5.0.0.p0.47/lib/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/webhdfs.py   480     copyfile
```

I found no oozie configuration related to max file size, and not sure if it is related to the Hadoop configuration or not. Have you ever met this case? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure but it might have been reported in the link of [hue issue](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/issues/151)